# Android orientation change uses wrong padding

Tags: android, android-orientation

We are supporting devices 2.3+. I have an activity with a Listview and would like for the data populated to be saved on orientation change but I rather not save the data and start populating the list with onSavedInstance. From API 14+ I need to register:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

I have different padding set on the Listview for portrait and landscape.
The problematic scenario: Whichever orientation I initially start the activity on that is the padding that is used on both orientations.
Tried to remove the "|screenSize" but then it doesn't take hold at all.
Values -

```
<dimen name="searchScreen_listViewPadding">25dp</dimen>
```

Values-land -

```
<dimen name="searchScreen_listViewPadding">150dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Show your first layout xml file.

Comment: The layout it the same. I just use different padding values from dimens.xml. I've edited.